# How to export data from NVidia Visual Profiler (nvvp)?

Tags: profiling, nvidia

I'm having a weird time reading from my application's profiling code on Linux so I decided to run it through NVidia Visual Profiler. On the toolkit 4.1 however they decided to remove the Compute Visual Profiler to introduce nvvp. I need to process the data outside the program, there's mean, deviation, confidence and a lot of statistical data that nvvp can't do. The problem is there is no export function in nvvp, the Compute Visual Profiler at least let you export to CSV. Is there a solution for this instead of installing the 4.0 toolkit?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Linux, I see a button in the bottom pane, "details" tab that has an "Export details in CSV format" tooltip.  The buttons don't show up under "analysis" or "settings" and are different under "console."

Does that do what you need?